# WOL to perform Post Reboot

Tags: windows-10, wake-on-lan, post

We have a scenario where some machines get stuck in POST and the fix is to simply reboot it, doing so, requires a physical reboot as PC is not fully boot and doesn't have network access, is it possible to achieve this task using WOL?

In other words, can WOL perform a reboot at POST?

Comment: If it doesn't have network access you can't do anything that requires it.

Comment: Does it have network access at post?

Comment: @Onluck - It probably does not, as the firmware, I/O capabilities.

Comment: @Ramhound how does pxe boot works then?

Comment: Looking into it, PXE would be a function of UEFI and thus would be available.  However, it functions, with a client and server relationship.  POST is well before that stage of the boot process.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you

Comment: The best solution is to find the reason for this and fix it before the computers fail totally.

Comment: @harrymc the error is "CPU over Temperature" and we haven't been able to fix it. I've tried every thing you can find on google.

Comment: Perhaps over-heating ?

Comment: yep, that's what the error indicates, but a simple reboot brings it back up and it works again, these are renderer machines that only render jobs

Comment: Perhaps it takes some time for the heat buildup. You should treat the heat problem - reboot is not a permanent solution.